# CheckBox Checked and Unchecked Event fires when scrolling a Listbox in windows phone 8 app?

Tags: windows-phone-7, xaml, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, checkedlistbox

I am developing a Windows Phone 8 App in which I am using a checkbox inside a listbox along with some textblocks.

```
<ListBox x:Name="lstStudentSelect"  ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource ListBoxItemStyle1}" Background="Transparent" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" Height="487" BorderThickness="0"  VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="8,198,10,0">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel   Orientation="Horizontal">
                <StackPanel Width="360" Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding stunum}" Width="80"   Foreground="Black"  TextWrapping="Wrap"  FontSize="20" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                    <TextBlock  Text="{Binding name}" Width="280"  Foreground="Black"  TextWrapping="Wrap"  FontSize="20" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                </StackPanel>
                <StackPanel Width="5"></StackPanel>
                <StackPanel Width="150" Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Right">
                    <CheckBox  IsChecked="{Binding ChkFlag, Mode=TwoWay}"  BorderBrush="#203485" Foreground="Black" BorderThickness="1" Tag="{Binding cusnum}" Name="cusCheck" Checked="cusCheck_Checked_2" Unchecked="cusCheck_Unchecked_2" ></CheckBox>
                    <TextBlock Text=" "  TextWrapping="Wrap" Foreground="Black" FontSize="20" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                </StackPanel>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

when I check/select on the checkbox the checkbox checked event fires, when I uncheck/unselect a checkbox the checkbox unchecked event fires.

**But now my issue is** :

When I am  scrolling  the listbox the checkbox checked and unchecked event fires automatically ?

How can I avoid this to happen ?

Comment: I just met the same problem. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36943494/466577) solved for me.

Answer (score 1):

Your issue relates to the fact you are binding the `IsChecked` property and have handlers for the `Checked` and `Unchecked` events. When the binding is updated and the property changes this will cause the events to fire.

Events will fire for each item when the `ItemsSource` is set/loaded.

By default the `ListBox` uses a virtualizing container for it's item panel. This means that as you scroll items will be loaded in and out of the container and this will also trigger events as a result of the binding changing. This is why you will see more events being triggered while you scroll. (Assuming you have a sufficiently large list to require virtualization.)

Assuming that `ChkFlag` is a property on your ViewModel and `cusCheck_Checked_2` & `cusCheck_Unchecked_2` are event handlers on your view, you could make things simpler for yourself and avoid this issue by moving the logic from the event handlers into the setter for `ChkFlag`. (This will probably also improve ease of testability too.)

For example, you could have a property like this:

```
    public bool ChkFlag
    {
        get
        {
            return this.chkFlagField;
        }

        set
        {
            if (this.chkFlagField != value)
            {
                this.chkFlagField = value;
                this.RaisePropertyChanged();

                if (value)
                {
                    // perform checked action
                }
                else
                {
                    // perform unchecked action
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative solution can be set a StackPanel as Panel.

```
<ListBox.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
        <StackPanel/>
    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
</ListBox.ItemsPanel>
```